# Using 2 pandas columns as arguments for np.timedelta

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, apply

Simple question:

```
In [1]:
df = DataFrame({'value':[4,4,4],'unit':['D','W','Y']})
df

Out[1]:
     unit   value
0    D      4
1    W      4
2    Y      4
```

I can create timedeltas this way (of course):

```
In [2]:
timedelta64(4, 'D')

Out[2]:
numpy.timedelta64(4,'D')
```

But I'm not being able to iterate through DataFrame columns to get a resulting Series with timedeltas:

```
def f(x):    
    return timedelta64(x['value'], x['unit'])

df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to float
```

**EDIT:**

This also does not work, and returns the same error:

```
df['arg'] = zip(df.value, df.unit)
df.arg.apply(lambda x: timedelta64(x[0], x[1]))
```

Comment: What are your `pandas` and `numpy` versions? Your code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @TomAugspurger pandas `0.12.0`, numpy `1.8.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your code works for me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[4,4,4],'unit':['D','W','Y']})
df.apply(f, axis=1)
0     4 days
1    4 weeks
2    4 years
dtype: object
```

Here's my versions:

```
numpy.__version__
'1.8.0'
pandas.__version__
'0.13.0rc1-32-g81053f9'
```

I did notice a bug perhaps related to your issue. You might check if you have numpy 1.7, if so upgrade to 1.8 and see if that fixes the issues. Good Luck :)

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5689

Answer (score 1):

In 0.13 this is supported using the new pd.to_timedelta:

```
In [24]: df = DataFrame({'value':[4,4,4],'unit':['D','W','Y']})

In [25]: pd.to_timedelta(df.apply(lambda x: np.timedelta64(x['value'],x['unit']), axis=1))
Out[25]: 
0      4 days, 00:00:00
1     28 days, 00:00:00
2   1460 days, 23:16:48
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```